# Simple Syntax Error in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Several times now I've gotten the error "ERROR:  syntax error at or near CREATE". I've played around with the formatting but can't seem to fix it. I'm hoping it's something minor someone can point out to me. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
-- View: mock_tool_cal

-- DROP VIEW mock_tool_cal;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW mock_tool_cal AS 
 SELECT toolcal."control#" AS old_control_number
   FROM staging.agg_staging_toolcal toolcal

ALTER TABLE mock_tool_cal
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Did you try CREATE  VIEW mock_tool_cal AS 
 SELECT toolcal."control#" AS old_control_number
   FROM staging.agg_staging_toolcal toolcal

Comment: There is no error in your view create query (see this demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0625b). It must be somewhere else. Show what you have before `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`.

Comment: @sany2k8 I just tried that out too, and no luck. I'm beginning to wonder if maybe it's a problem with the SQL admin program I'm using.

Comment: @Rahul I think that SQLFiddle confirms my suspicion. And I don't have anything in the ddl prior to "Create or Replace View"

Answer (score 2):

You need a semicolon between the `CREATE` and `ALTER` commands

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW mock_tool_cal AS 
SELECT toolcal."control#" AS old_control_number
FROM staging.agg_staging_toolcal toolcal

;

ALTER TABLE mock_tool_cal
OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! As it turns out it was a problem with PGAdmin3. I was writing out the entire DDL, but hadn't realized it was already inserting "Create View mock_tool_cal". This meant I had two "Create View mock_tool_cal" lines hence the syntactical error.